# Disagree with "Removed unrelated, self-promotional link"

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette, moderation, self-promotion

I just had "Removed unrelated, self-promotional link" note on 2 of my answers from Andrew Barber.

Actually, specially for answering questions like that, I had discussion with Apple engineers, created sample code and pushed it to GitHub.

But now, when I point to that repo, my answers get an "unrelated, self-promotional link " mark.

> [image: Unrelated, self-promotional link]

Comment: It's not clear why you're mentioning having discussions with Apple engineers. They don't have any authority over what's appropriate on SO.

Comment: You had the discussion with Apple and developed the app "specially for answering questions like that." So are you a sponsored candidate?

Comment: given that editor is a [moderator](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75189/165773), it is most likely that this was done per [meta-tag:flags] from regular users

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion nope, i just find it quite useful to have app that demonstrates solving issue completely in right way (there's lack of documentation about that topic).

Answer (score 26):

Your answer, which you copy/pasted to several Stack Overflow questions, was:

> I have sample app that demonstrates how to calculate spectrum of playing sound stream https://github.com/666tos/SpectrumAnalyzerSample

In general, copy/pasting a [link-only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) to several Stack Overflow questions is a bad approach.  If the answers you are posting are the same because the questions are the same, then the questions should be closed as duplicates of each other.  If the questions are different, then you need to tailor your answer to each question specifically, and *answer the question in your answer, not in an offsite link.*

Kate Gregory [eloquently and succinctly describes the requirements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94027/102937) that our community has for links back to your blog, software or other product:

> In my experience, posts with links are not downvoted if all these
>   conditions are met:
>
> - you paraphrase the content of the linked item (possibly omitting details or examples)
> - you identify the author (yourself, MSDN, etc)
> - **someone could benefit from the answer without reading the linked item at all**
> - you include information to let the reader decide if clicking the link is worthwhile
>
> For example:
>
> > You can use the CircularLabelsStyle
> >     custom property for this, for example:
> >
> > ```
> >   chart1.Series["Series1"]["CircularLabelsStyle"] = "Circular";
> > ```
> >
> > I [blogged
> >     about this last year](http://example.com), with some sample
> >     code.
>
> The other extreme, an answer that says nothing more than "here" or
>   "read this" or "please read" and is a link, I will not just downvote
>   but flag as not an answer, and I don't care whether it's the
>   definitive documentation from the owner of the technology, another
>   question on the same SE site, or just a blog you wrote yourself.

Links that you include in your posts must be supportive; that is:

1. They should supplement your answer, not be the actual answer, and
2. They should be *directly relevant to the answer you provide.*

Comment: The question isn't about link-only answers or duplicate answers, but about irrelevant self-promotional links being removed from otherwise valid answers ([one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697336/uisplitviewcontroller-detail-only-inputaccessoryview/25013447#25013447), [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24634795/keyboard-handling-just-like-in-messages-app-in-ios-7/25013674#25013674)). The text you've quoted here isn't what was removed from those two answers.

Comment: All of the advice I gave here still applies.  If the answer is insufficient, I'm sure the OP will not be shy in telling me that.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: See also [my most recent edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25013447/5) to his post.  The OP seems to demonstrate an unfamiliarity with our platform.

Comment: I think responding to their question by discussing different material than what they specifically asked about is likely to cause more confusion.

Comment: A problem you remedied by providing your own answer to the question.

Comment: @Andrew OP specifically mentioned that she developed the app solely for "answering such questions" backed by Apple. This answer is more relevant to OP's question.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: I've added a clarification to the bottom of my answer.  I trust that suffices.

Comment: @pnuts: Are you kidding?  If you aren't, I have some [swamp land in Florida](http://www.realtor.com/florida/nbselfl.asp) I can sell you.

Comment: @pnuts: Apparently you didn't carefully read that article.  It says *"Provide context for links -- 
Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there."*  **Relevance is implied.**

Comment: @pnuts: What does that have to do with "Your links must be relevant"?

Comment: That's quite funny that such kind of solving issue and also whole set of related problems (providing sample) is potentially punishable, but providing answers with strange code is OK (but that never solves the problem).

Answer (score 7):

Your [most recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24634795/keyboard-handling-just-like-in-messages-app-in-ios-7/25013674#25013674) was on a question about making the iOS keyboard appear/disappear with a text field. The majority of your answer does respond to that, but "if you need to have your text field resizable, check my sample code" doesn't answer the question (the question isn't about making a text field resizable) - so it's just an unrelated self-promotional link.

Comment: I would say that the whole link-only discussion doesn't apply to the two answers specified in the question. The content was removed for being irrelevant to the question, not just for being a link. It would have been equally irrelevant and equally subject to removal if it had been a mention of a project without a link, or pasted code.

Comment: The other answer had a ~40 minute head start and was already up to at least 10 before I posted mine, so I'm guessing this isn't getting as much visibility.